# Geoserver2.6. REST cURL automation to add GeoTIFFs (batch)

Tags: geoserver, curl

I would like to add and publish hundreds of GeoTIFFs to my GeoServer datastore. I have started to write a batch file to manage GeoServer by REST API.
I have finally figured out how to create a new workspace and datastore. But do not know how to add hundreds of GeoTIFFs from a local folder. I have tried to use a loop and wildcards.I cannot figure it out.

For the following code I got the error message:

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
uebung1.bat: line 28: http://loclahost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/DPP/datastores/BarometricPressure: No such file or directory
mat80localhost 138 <.../TERENO_StationViewer/batch>:
```

Here is the batch-code:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XGET -H 'Accept: text/xml'\
    "http://loclahost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces" 
echo "" 
echo ""
echo ""
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' \
     -d '<workspace><name>DDP</name></workspace>'\
     "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces"

echo "----- Then create the datastore. ------------------------------------"
echo ""
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: application/xml' \
     -d '<coverageStore><name>BarometricPressure</name><workspace>DDP</workspace>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <type>GeoTIFF</type>
      <url>/misc/klima2/monitoring/climate_data/raster/BarometricPressure/2014/</url>
         </coverageStore>'\
  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/DDP/coveragestores?configure=all"
echo ""
echo ""
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XGET -H 'Accept: text/xml'\
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces 
echo ""
echo ""
for f in *tif; do
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: image/tiff' \
-d "$f %.tif"
"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/DPP/datastores/BarometricPressure";
```

Comment: are your tifs actually called file.tiff or are they file.tif - in which case you only want 1 f in %.tiff

Comment: I get bad substitution when I try your last line, as you don't need brace expansion (I don't think). Try `for f in *tiff; do
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: image/tiff' \
-d $f ....` instead, ie, replace "${f %.tiff}" with $f.

Comment: good points I updated the code but still...

Comment: Its not easy to see because you still haven't told us what your data looks like, but that error you've posted indicates that `loclahost` isn't a valid host name. Perhaps you meant `localhost`? There is probably also a missing `done` at the end of the script.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having trouble curling my tif's over to the server, using the example above for just 1 file I get 'Could not resolve host: image'